# What do propositional function in ZFC mean?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I know that a propositional function is a WFF which can be either true or false depending on the value of at least one variable.

The axiom schema of specification (subsets) says that for every propositional function $P(z)$ we can create an axiom ${\forall}x({\exists}y:({\forall}z((z{\in}y){\iff}((z{\in}x){\land}(P(z))))))$

Is this propositional function a WFF in first order logic? Higher order logic? Arbitrary order logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $P(z)$ is just a wff in the first-order language of set theory that may contain $z$ free.

In order to get the ZFC axiom scheme *as usually presented*
, one has to clarify that $P(z)$ can also contain other parameter variables free, as long as it doensn't contain $y$ (or $x$) free.

(As Andrés Caicedo points out below, though, such parameters are not strictly necessary -- instead, with a bit of ingenuity, if one needs a parameter $A$ one can construct for example
$$ \bar x = \{\; \{\{y\},\{\varnothing,\{A\}\}\} \mid y\in x \} $$
using only the Power Set, Pairing, Union and parameter-less Separation/Specification axioms, then select the appropriate packages from $\bar x$ without parameters, and finally unwrap the selected packages with a few more Union and Separation steps).

Comment: Sure you never need $x$ as a parameter? Kunen uses that sometimes.

Comment: @Pedro: If you do, you can just use a different letter for the parameter and then instantiate this letter and $x$ to the same thing when you apply the axiom. So it doesn't matter whether one allows using $x$ as a parameter or not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Lack of parameters is not a failing. The parameter free version of the axioms has been known to imply the usual one since Levy. A quick presentation of the equivalence is [here](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/logik/Personen/rds/ZFC_without_parameters.pdf).

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo: Ingenious; I wasn't aware of that. Better now?

Comment: Why is it only allowed to be a first order WFF? I can't see the reason for it solely from the way the axiom is phrased.

Comment: @cxzcxzcas: Because ZFC, **by definition**, is a first-order theory. If the formula was not a first-order wff, the resulting theory would have axioms that were not first-order formulas, and it wouldn't even be possible to reason about them with first-order logic.